# Seg Fault in C Hash Table implementation

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I've been working on this dynamic memory allocator problem set where we must implement malloc and free and I was struggling a lot with the implementation of free. Outside of freeing the appropriate memory, there is a statistics struct that we must update with each call of malloc/free which holds a variable for the size of active allocations, active_size. To accurately update active_size the problem set says we should implement a hash table. I made the hash table to hold malloc pointers and the size of their allocations and I included a lookup_size function which would then be used in the free function to update the active_size. However, it seems the lookup_size functions is flawed and causes a seg fault at this line:

```
return tmp->payload;
```

I'll leave below the entire code as well in case anyone catches any other mistakes, but it would be a huge help if someone could figure out the cause of this seg fault. Thanks.

```
#define M61_DISABLE 1
#include "m61.hh"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cassert>

// Hash table size
#define TABLE_SIZE 10

/// m61_malloc(sz, file, line)
///    Return a pointer to `sz` bytes of newly-allocated dynamic memory.
///    The memory is not initialized. If `sz == 0`, then m61_malloc must
///    return a unique, newly-allocated pointer value. The allocation
///    request was at location `file`:`line`.
static m61_statistics stat_count = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4294967295};

// Hash table item defintion
typedef struct ht_item {
    void* address;
    unsigned long long payload;
    struct ht_item* next;
} ht_item;

// Initialize hash table
ht_item* hash_table[TABLE_SIZE];

// Mod hash function
int hash_func(void* address) {
    uintptr_t hash_value = (uintptr_t) address % TABLE_SIZE;
    return hash_value;
}

// Empty hash table
void init_hash_table() {
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

// Hash table item insertion function
bool insert_item(ht_item* item) {
    // Check if there actually is an item
    if (item == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    // Insert item to front of the l_list (assign current val to next and new value to hash table)
    int index = hash_func(item->address);
    item->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = item;
    return true;
}

// Hash table functiont that finds allocated sizes by mallocc
unsigned long long lookup_size(void* p) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    int index = hash_func(p); 
    ht_item* tmp = hash_table[index];
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->address != p) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return tmp->payload;
}

void* m61_malloc(size_t sz, const char* file, long line) {
    (void) file, (void) line;   // avoid uninitialized variable warnings
    // Your code here.
    if (!base_malloc(sz)){
        ++stat_count.nfail;
        stat_count.fail_size += sz;
    }

    else {
        ++stat_count.nactive;
        ++stat_count.ntotal;
        stat_count.active_size += sz;
        stat_count.total_size += sz;

        init_hash_table();
        void* p = base_malloc(sz);
        ht_item* malloc_data = (ht_item*) malloc(sizeof(ht_item));
        malloc_data->address = p;
        malloc_data->payload = sz;
        malloc_data->next = NULL;
        insert_item(malloc_data);
    }
    return base_malloc(sz);
}


/// m61_free(ptr, file, line)
///    Free the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which must have been
///    returned by a previous call to m61_malloc. If `ptr == NULL`,
///    does nothing. The free was called at location `file`:`line`.

void m61_free(void* ptr, const char* file, long line) {
    (void) file, (void) line;   // avoid uninitialized variable warnings
    // Your code here.
    if (ptr){
        --stat_count.nactive;
        stat_count.active_size -= lookup_size(ptr);
    }
    base_free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Your `m61_malloc` function makes no sense to me. You allocate up to 3 times (via `base_malloc`)  and what you insert into the hash table does not hold the address that the function returns

Comment: And while you did not provide a [mre]  I assume that you pass the pointer you returned from `m61_malloc` to `lookup_size` - which (as per my previous comment) is not the pointer that you actually stored in your `hash_table`. So the lookup will fail (and the `return tmp->payload;` line will also be executed if `tmp` is a null pointer)

Comment: _Side note:_ If `item->address` comes from something similar to `malloc`, the address is usually aligned to an 8 byte boundary, so the lower 3 bits will always be 0. This means that a number of hash buckets will never be used (e.g. buckets 0-7). To compensate for this, in `hash_function` you may want: `uintptr_t hash_value = ((uintptr_t) address >> 3) % TABLE_SIZE;` Actually, although slower, a _sum_ of all the bytes in `address` might be a better hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into the answer, let me say this:

Dropping a chunk of memory management code on someone with no way to run it besides reverse-engineering the code from compiler output until it works is not nice.

Please, take a good look at this link before asking another question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

---

So, you have this snippet of code:

```
while (tmp != NULL && tmp->address != p) {
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
return tmp->payload;
```

Look at the loop condition:

```
while (tmp != NULL && tmp->address != p) { ... }
```

Assuming `tmp->address` never equals `p`, it keeps iterating as long as `tmp` is not `NULL`. In other words, it stops when `tmp` is `NULL`.

Then, in the very next line, you try to access `tmp`. But `tmp` is already `NULL` at that point! So you pretty much do this:

```
return NULL->payload;
```

And that's what causes the segmentation fault.

If this loop is meant to always succeed when free is called on a valid pointer, then you're probably not reliably calling `insert_item` in some case (in `m61_malloc`)?

Or, if `insert_item` should not be called on every call to `m61_malloc`, then you would not expect to find the item on every call to `lookup_size`, so you should check that `tmp` is not `NULL` after the loop. (you should probably do this regardless, because someone might call `m61_free` with an invalid pointer).

---

As for the cause of this bug, `m61_malloc` seems pretty fishy...

```
if (!base_malloc(sz)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
    void* p = base_malloc(sz);
    ...
}
return base_malloc(sz);
```

What do you expect this to do when the first call to `base_malloc` does not return `NULL`? As it stands, it goes into the 'else' branch, calls `base_malloc` a second time (either allocating again or returning a `NULL` that isn't handled), then calls `base_malloc` a third time in the return statement (again, possibly returning `NULL`).

In this scenario, the pointer that is stored in the hash table is the one that was returned by the second call to `base_malloc`, but the pointer that is returned (and that might be passed into `m61_free` later) is the one returned by the third call to `base_malloc` (which is NOT stored in the hash table).

Maybe this is the true cause of the error?

EDIT: changing `m61_malloc` as below fixes this particular segfault, though it's still wrong.

```
if (!base_malloc(sz)) {
    ...
    return NULL;
} else {
    ...
    void* p = base_malloc(sz);
    ...
    return p;
}
```

Comment: First — Thanks for the quick reply, I’ve been hung up over this problem set forever lol. 

If the loop is making tmp into NULL, then I get that you’re essentially dereferencing a null pointer which produces the seg fault. When you call lookup_size with one of the malloc pointers it was intended to always succeed, so I’m not sure whether there’s a problem with insert like you said or maybe even the hashing of the addresses? What other thoughts do you have? Also pay little mind to m61_malloc and base_malloc stuff — it’s just the weird base code of the pset that I haven’t fully parsed through.

Comment: @azimr24 I just edited the answer. Take a second look at it. And please look at this link before asking more questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Got it. It’s my first time posting, so I’ll better format my question. Thanks

Comment: @azimr24 No problem! If my answer was helpful, don't hesitate to upvote/mark as correct by clicking the upwards arrow or the tick mark, near the start of the answer.

As for what causes this bug, I'm pretty sure the problem is in `m61_malloc`, and not in `m61_free` (like I mentioned at the end of my answer).

As a final note, keep in mind that comments are not meant for extended discussion. To add more details and information, you can edit your question and use comments to notify about the edits. This helps you get an answer from passersby by having all information in one place.